# Discards the last ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this program which should be stored in a txt file the information requested by keyboard, but this does not save the last request would be an ArrayList called "cole " if I could help with this please.

```
package lab1;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Lab1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     // TODO code application logic here

    int opc;
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("MENU: Eligue su opcion\n");
    System.out.println("1.- Crear archivo");
    System.out.println("2.- Mas opciones para mostrar");
    System.out.println("3.- Escritura en el archivo");
    System.out.println("4.- Salir\n");
    System.out.println("Introdusca su opcion:");
    opc = entrada.nextInt();

    if (opc == 1){
        FileWriter fichero = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try{

        //Tiempo al programa de suspencion.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            //se abre el archivo txt si este esta creado y el TRUE hace que no borre la informacio que este contiene si es que existe el txt.
            fichero = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Levenor\\Desktop\\Test\\test.txt", true);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fichero);

            //En estos parametros se pide la informacion para agregarlo en una lista para luego colocar en el txt.

            ArrayList<String> nombre = new ArrayList<String>();
            System.out.println("Ingrese Nombre: ");
            nombre.add(entrada.nextLine());
            Thread.sleep(8000);

            ArrayList<String> rut = new ArrayList<String>();
            System.out.println("Ingrese RUT: ");
            rut.add(entrada.nextLine());
            Thread.sleep(8000);

            ArrayList<String> edad = new ArrayList<String>();
            System.out.println("Ingrese EDAD: ");
            edad.add(entrada.nextLine());
            Thread.sleep(4000);

            // here is arraylist is not save in the archive txt    

            ArrayList<String> cole = new ArrayList<String>();
            System.out.println("Ingrese COLEGIO: ");
            cole.add(entrada.nextLine());
            Thread.sleep(4000);

            //Esta linea hace que las listas se guarden en el archivo de txt.
            pw.println("" +nombre +rut +edad +cole);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
            // Nuevamente aprovechamos el finally para
            // asegurarnos que se cierra el fichero.
            if (null != fichero)
                fichero.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have an empty line in test.txt ?  Split the following statement: `cole.add(entrada.nextLine());` into three steps: `String line = entrada.nextLine(); System.out.println("The line that is not saved is: " + line); cole.add(line);` this will help you see what's going on.

Comment: @alfasin the issue is that `nextInt()` doesn't consume the newline character, so you need a call for `nextLine()` to advance the scanner to match the input. See my answer below.

Comment: It's spelled "introduzca", not "introdusca"; also it's "opción" - with an accent. What a bad orthography :(

Comment: @doublesharp between the call to `nextInt` and this specific `nextLine` call - there are three other `nextLine` calls that work fine, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @alfasin You are misunderstanding. When you call `nextLine()` it advances the scanner past the next newline. When you call `nextInt()` it consumes the `int`, but does not consume the newline. If you run my sample code, you will see it working.

Comment: @doublesharp I'm pretty sure I *did* understand, and what you're suggesting would have solved the problem if `nombre` would have come up as empty, not `cole`.

Comment: @alfasin trust me, you are incorrect. just run my sample code. the inputs were not aligned, `nombre` i in the wrong place which is why `cole` is never collected, which is why nothing is written to the file.

Comment: As I wrote, when I run his code, what I get is `[][rut][edad][cole]` which means that `nombre` is missing. If that's the problem - then your solution is correct, only that the OP wrote that he's not getting `cole`. In this case, I don't see how to reproduce the problem (and, your solution is irrelevant).

Answer (score 0):

You are a missing a call for [`entrada.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) after `opc = entrada.nextInt();` - it isn't advancing the input properly. When you call [`entrada.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) it consumes the `int` value, but not the newline character at the end. Thus you need a call to `nextLine()` to move the `Scanner` past it.

The system should also pause - you don't need to use `Thread.sleep()` - this is a symptom of it not aligning to your input properly. You should also make sure to close the `Scanner entrada` in the `finally` block.

***Example code:***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introdusca su opcion:");

    // Get the int value here, but not the newline
    int opc = entrada.nextInt();

    // **** Advance to the next line here ****
    entrada.nextLine();

    if (opc == 1){
        try{
            System.out.println("Ingrese Nombre:");
            String nombre = entrada.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Ingrese RUT:");
            String rut = entrada.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Ingrese EDAD:");
            String edad = entrada.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Ingrese COLEGIO:");  
            String cole = entrada.nextLine();

            System.out.println("nombre: " + nombre);
            System.out.println("rut: " + rut);
            System.out.println("edad: " + edad);
            System.out.println("cole: " + cole);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // make sure to close the Scanner
            entrada.close();
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

***Example output:***

```
Introdusca su opcion:
1
Ingrese Nombre:
nombre
Ingrese RUT:
rut
Ingrese EDAD:
edad
Ingrese COLEGIO:
colegio

nombre: nombre
rut: rut
edad: edad
cole: colegio
```